# When I aquire a domain from a competitor is there SEO value in redirecting or keeping the existing site?

Tags: seo, domains

I can aquire a domain from the competition. For best SEO, do I place 301 redirect to my site on it or should I keep the site link from it?

#### Situation

Another sites ranks #1 (A) in Google and my site ranks 4 (B). I can acquire the domain ranking 2 (C) by acquisition.

#### Question

Is this a chance one should not miss? And for best ranking results, would you place a 301 on the acquired domain (C) pointing to your domain (B)? Or would you keep the site (C) in the air, but place a huge banner directing all customers to your site (B)?

It sounds like placing a 301 only has a temporary effect. But I am not sure of this one. and maybe this question has been asked before - I couldn't find it - reading up on an article giving some tips would also be great.

Comment: Keep in mind that Google and Bing both look at registration information and other data to create relationships between sites. Google in particular is very good at it. If you acquire some domains and 301 them to your original domain, Google will realize that you are juicing-up and the original domains will lose value over time. Perhaps faster than you would like. I would only acquire a domain if there is real value to the name or any content you may inherit. Otherwise forget it. Focus on making your original domain better. There are no shortcuts in SEO so don't look for one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, linking from within the same industry does not provide value. In some cases can incur a penalty.

I once worked on a project where, we'll say plumbers, started linking to other plumbers not in their area, for SEO purposes. This ended up getting all of the plumbers banned from the index. This ban took 2 years to fix, and required some internal lobbying from within the search company that imposed the ban.

Some takeaways from that experience:

Why would a plumber link to another plumber? There is no value for anyone there
Linking for the sake of SEO will always be risky, best to do it the the whitest of hats on

If I was you, I'd 301 domain C to domain B. Some value for some time yes, but you'd also be removing the URL at #2... Additionally, any direct traffic from C would go to B, that included links in directories and bookmarks.